# Useful Momentum Relation for Relativistic Particles

Tags: special-relativity, energy, particle-physics, momentum, mass-energy

I've seen that $$p = \sqrt{(\frac{E}{c})^2-(mc)^2} = \frac{1}{c} \sqrt{{E_k}^2 + 2 E_0 E_k}$$ for a relativistic particle on hyperphysics and in my modern physics class. I understand that the first part of the equality follows directly from the energy momentum relation $$E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$$ but I don't see how to get from the middle expression to the one on the right.

What trick should I apply to get from one to the other here? I'm completely lost on what has been called "just algebra" as usual.

Comment: Your first equation is incorrect.  I think you copied it wrong from where you saw it.

Comment: And this is a typical homework type of problem, and involves straightforward algebra and proper definitions for relativistic momentum and kinetic energy.  If you pay attention to the algebraic details and take your time, it's not difficult.

Comment: this is not a homework question. This is a question about a general topic that I trying to use to understand the already complete and correct answer that I got for a homework problem using the identity. For reference, the HW question that this question stemmed from is the following: "Electrons in an electron microscope are accelerated from rest through a potential
difference $V_0$ so that their de Broglie wavelength is 0.04 nm.  What is $V_0$?"

Comment: Also I fixed the middle term

Comment: @BillN said it is a "homework type of problem" and gives a valid reason why. Your question can be answered purely from using definitions and algebra and is not concerned with understanding physics concepts. Hence calling it a "homework-like problem" where you are manipulating equations rather than discussing physics concepts.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to apply the definitions to proceed. I don't know if this question would be better placed on a different stack exchange (maybe math, but they're not necessarily going to have the definitions from physics), but I really don't see how these are equal; without that, I don't "understand" my solution to the problem in terms of the natural laws I'm applying. So, it is about understanding, which is tied to successful algebra. I disagree with you. I would have asked for a full solution if I just wanted work done for me. An answer like robphy's is more like what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Rapidity**" (the Minkowski analogue of the angle) is often a good thing since your experience with Euclidean trig identities can guide you towards **hyperbolic-trig identities** which underlie the less familiar identities 
among $\{ v, \gamma, v\gamma, \mbox{ and } 1\}$ 
or among $\{ v, E, p, \mbox{ and } m\}$, especially to a new student of the subject.

It's easier if $c=1$, but I'll leave it in.
With $v=c\tanh\theta$, we have $\gamma=\cosh\theta$
 (since $1\equiv\cosh^2\theta-\sinh^2\theta=\cosh^2\theta(1-\tanh^2\theta)$).

Then
the relativistic energy is $E=(mc^2)\cosh\theta$ and
the relativistic momentum is $pc=(mc^2)\sinh\theta$,
and
the kinetic energy is $E_k=E-mc^2=(mc^2)\cosh\theta-(mc^2)=(mc^2)(\cosh\theta-1)$
and
the rest energy is $E_0=(mc^2)$.

The above can be used in many relativity problems... not just this one.

For your problem, rather than go from the middle to the right,
 
try starting from the right [which is more obscure]
 and get the middle [which is more familiar]. 

Plug in $E_k$ and $E_0$ and simplify.

Then undo your steps if you want to find a route from middle to right.

(In my opinion, it's better to learn this general technique, 
than to derive numerous analogous but obscure/specialized identities.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found working backwards with your identities very helpful and was able to prove both statements that way from the energy-momentum relation $E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$.